# Conditional row subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using sql server 2005.

I have two columns a and b.

I wish to subtract b from a to produce c, which I do as follows:

a - b as c

but I want to complement this by having c = 0 if a or b is 0. How do I do this?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **case**

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN a = 0 OR b = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE a - b 
   END c
```

More on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using a `CASE` statement is definitly the most recommended way but for fun and pleasure, using some bit shifting would work as well

```
c = ABS(a - b) 
    * (((CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF)) 
    / POWER(2, 16) / POWER(2, 15))
```

**Steps taken**

1. Multiply to get either a zero (a or b is zero) or non-zero (a and b both <> 0) value. The non-zero value needs to get converted to 1

   `ABS(a * b)`
2. Cast to `BIGINT` to prevent `Arithmetic overflow`

   `CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)`
3. Make sure bit 32 is set to 1 if `ABS(a * b)` was a non-zero value.

   `CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF`
4. Shift 31 bits retaining either a 0 or 1. *(Because POWER returns an int this has to be done in two steps instead of a simpler POWER(2, 31))*

   `((CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF))`
   `/ POWER(2, 16) / POWER(2, 15)`
5. Multiply the original equation with our calculated 0 or 1.

   `ABS(a - b)`
   `* (((CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF))`
   `/ POWER(2, 16) / POWER(2, 15))`

**Test script**

```
;WITH q (a, b) AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
      (0, 0)
    , (0, 1)
    , (0, 2)
    , (1, 0)
    , (1, 1)
    , (1, 2)
    , (2, 0)
    , (2, 1)
    , (2, 2)
    , (9, 0)
    , (9, 1)
    , (9, 2)
  ) a (b, c)
)
SELECT  a
        , b
        , c = ABS(a - b) 
              * (((CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF)) 
              / POWER(2, 16) / POWER(2, 15))
FROM    q
```

**Edit**

As in comments we wondered about performance differences, following is a quick test setup.

**Performance test setup**

```
CREATE TABLE q (a INTEGER, b INTEGER)
;WITH numbers (a) AS (
    SELECT  0
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  a + 1
    FROM    numbers
    WHERE   a < 999
)
INSERT  INTO q
SELECT  a1.a, a2.a
FROM    numbers a1
        CROSS APPLY numbers a2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Performance Test**

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT  c = (a - b)
              * (((CAST(ABS(a * b) AS BIGINT)+0x7FFFFFFF)) 
              / POWER(2, 16) / POWER(2, 15))
FROM    q

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN a = 0 OR b = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE a - b 
   END c
FROM    q
```

Comment: @cairnz - As in *"Oh... My... God..."* ? :)

Comment: More like my first thought is : Would this be more or less cpu costly than a case when, and where would this be more applicable than a case when. Also, readability would make this kind of fun. :)'

Comment: The `elapsed time` on a one million rows table is `11603ms` for the case variant and `10827ms` for the bitshifting variant. A 6% performance increase using bit shifting *in my particular test setup* but hardly worth the loss in readability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should do it :)

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN A=0 OR B=0 THEN 0 ELSE A-B END AS C
FROM 
 TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try his:

```
 SELECT 
 a,b,
 CASE
    WHEN a = 0 OR  b = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE
       a - b
 END AS c
 FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b,    
       COALESCE(NULLIF(a, 0) - NULLIF(b, 0), 0) AS c
  FROM T1;
```

Or

```
SELECT a, b, 0 AS c
  FROM T1
 WHERE 0 IN (a, b)
UNION
SELECT a, b, a - b AS c
  FROM T1
 WHERE 0 NOT IN (a, b);
```

Note each handles nulls differently (you spec does not mention how to handle nulls).